# How can I solve The Riddle of Nine 9's programmatically?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

How can I solve this riddle programmatically? Could someone help me with some pseudo-code or something?

**Nine 9s**

Combining nine 9's with any number of the operators +, -, *, /, (, ), what is the smallest positive integer that cannot be expressed?

**Hints:**

1. The answer isn't zero. You can express zero like this:
   (9 - 9) * (9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9 + 9).
   Also, zero isn't a positive integer.
2. The answer isn't one. You can express one like this:
   9 - (9 * 9 - 9)/9 + 9 - 9 + 9 - 9
3. It's not a trick question.
4. Be sure to handle parentheses correctly.

**Notes:**

- You cannot use exponentiation.
- You cannot concatenate (for example,
  put two 9's together to make 99).
- The - operator can be used in either
  its binary or unary form.
- Assume base 10.

---

This is actually a famous puzzle and there are probably many solutions hovering around the internet.  I am not sure if any of them is correct or not. Does anybody have a well explained solution?

Comment: Is operator overloading admitted? :S

Comment: @:closers: why off topic? Mind to explain?

Comment: I see this as off-topic for two main reasons. (1) This problem does not fundamentally have anything to do with programming - it's a **math** question. (2) Are you trying to solve a particular problem? Are you trying to create a `Code Golf` question? What have you tried so far? I don't see anything along those lines. ...and what's up with your dollar-sign notation?

Comment: @Matt Ball: I think that the dollar-sign notation comes from LaTeX.

Comment: @Matt Ball - The OP has asked for help with an approach to solve the puzzle programmatically, therefore it is entirely on topic.  Besides which maths within code is generally on-topic.

Comment: Comes from LaTeX and does formatting on math.stackexchange.com, but not here.  Though the question is a bit vague, it IS on topic.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: I keep thinking they need to get the support for LaTeX maths working on StackOverflow, Mathematics has it, so StackOverflow could too.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks,at-least you explained your behavior ,(1)It's essentially related to programming and cannot be solved without it:)you may try looking at link suggested in answer.(2)Yes,No,I have tried to solve it with maths but rather not there. and I initially thought to posted in math.stackexchange so wrote it with assuming latex format,then I came to know that's it's can;t be solved without programming so I posted it here.

Comment: @Matteo: looks like you're right. @Philando: please take the time to format your questions by [site standards](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Stack Overflow does not parse LaTeX, as you may have noticed.

Comment: For the future reader: I just removed the latex $formatting$.

Comment: I am not sure how programming can be `entirely` separated from  mathematics, since most of the programming I do are just asthmatics talking into code :) So I guess we should have Latex support here too.

Comment: @Orbling: is, it would be really nice to have LaTeX math support also here, now and then it comes handy even here on SO to have nice math formulas. And if the code is already there for math.stackexchange.com I don't think it would be difficult to port it here. But I'm going OT.

Comment: It's really harsh this topic is closed as off-topic!

Comment: I started a discussion on this in meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72603/why-is-this-closed-as-off-topic

Comment: @Philando Gullible: Agreed, voted to reopen.  Non-mathematical coders everywhere it seems, an oxymoron I had hoped.

Comment: @Philando Gullible Voted to re-open, even though I originally voted to close. You made a fair argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is 195, here is some Python code that simply builds up all possible expressions by forming new expressions from `exp1 OP exp2`. It runs in 0.165s on my PC.

```
exp = [set() for _ in xrange(10)]
exp[0].add(0)
exp[1].update([9, -9])
for i in xrange(1, 10):
  for a in list(exp[i]):
    for j in xrange(i, 10):
      for b in list(exp[j-i]):
        exp[j].update([a+b, a-b, a*b])
        if b != 0:
          exp[j].add(a/b)

n = 0
while n in exp[9]:
  n += 1
print n
```

---

*EDIT:*
If the answers must be exact integers (and not just the rounded result of integer division) then a check must be done when division is done.

```
    if ((b != 0) and ((a/b) == float(a)/b)):
      exp[j].add(a/b)
```

Under this interpretation of the rules, the new answer is 138.
(the existing version computes 1386/10 [or -1386/-10] and gets 138)

Answer (score 6):

195, http://members.iinet.net.au/~tmorrow/mathematics/ninenines/ninenines.html